# Wired USB mouse stops working on desktop

Tags: wireless, usb, mouse

completely new to Ubuntu, but getting away from windows and mac. Basically my USB wired mouse stops working after a few minutes being on, I've tried with other computers and the mouse worked fine, tried a wireless USB mouse, same problem, this has only started to occur in past week or so, I've tried following tips etc on here & youtube and the longest I've had out of it is about ten minutes without opening any programs. Using 14.04 if that helps, just need someone to say "yeah, just do this..."
If you need me to send over tech details, let me know how, as it's a tadge different from windows!

Cheers guys.

Comment: do you have tlp or some other power management application set up like jupiter or laptopmode tools? That sounds like a power management feature turning off the usb port to save on power. If using tlp you need to edit your conf file to prevent this.

Comment: no, don't believe I do, but I did see a post on disabling auto powersave (or words to that effect) and did as shown in the terminal. But just to be sure, where would I find the settings?

Comment: IDK i only know for TLP but doesn't sound like you have that installed. What command did you run?

Comment: errrrrrrrrm, hang on I'm looking!

Comment: you can usually press the up arrow in a terminal to go through your last commands run

Comment: just realised I restored back to old restore point earlier (92 days ago) so I can't see the command, but as said before, the issue has only arisen in the past week.

Comment: Does the same behavior happen on Windows? You could have had a hardware failure since installing Ubuntu. Also, when the mouse stops working, does it turn off or does it just stop accepting input? In other words, does the infrared light on the bottom go off? Finally, have you tried different USB ports?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
echo "on" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/level
```

You may need to redo this command after you reboot. To verify the setting is still in place after you reboot, run the following command:

```
cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/level
```

The output should say "on" and should *not* say "auto". If the output says "auto", you will need to run the first command above again to prevent autosuspend.

modified from source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1164895

---

**EDIT:**

If the above doesn't work. You can try setting a command for the kernel by running the following commands:

```
sudo sed -i 's/quiet/usbcore.autosuspend=-1 quiet/g' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and then run the following command:

```
cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
```

and the output should now be -1

---

Other methods include the following:

```
echo "-1" | sudo tee /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
```

or

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
```

and some systems may require this instead:

```
echo "-1" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
```

[unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91027/how-to-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-kernel-3-7-10-or-above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91027/how-to-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-kernel-3-7-10-or-above)

Comment: I will try in a mo, but funny thing just occured; I plugged in a wireless dongle and had no issues at all, unplugged it an instantly the problem started again...

Comment: ok, sorry I haven't been back (work), wireless dongle hasn't changed anything, just a fluke I suppose. I've entered the commands as asked and rebooted to no avail, tis a bother...

Comment: @FrancisSaunders I believe you may have misread. You may have to run the command again *after* you reboot.

Comment: Hi guys, yeah, ran the command after reboot too, no change.

Comment: Hi guys, been nearly 2 months and after reinstallation, the above code, changing mouse and praying to the big fella upstairs nothing has changed! In real need of inspiration, what do I do?!?!